# How to make the join between two collections in Slamdata

Tags: mongodb, slamdata

I have a poblem in the join between two mongodb collections:

select   leave. *,
         employ. *
From '/ leaveRequest' as leave inner join '/ employee' as employ
on employ._id = leave.employee. $id

the error that appears  $  not found

NB: the method used by mongo is DBREFS.
I blocked at this stage, can you help me and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug in Quasar, the open source project used by SlamData. I suggest reporting the bug on [Github](http://github.com/quasar-analytics/quasar/issues) and editing your answer when and if a fix is made available.